# How do I find a general formula for $\int_0^\infty e^{-(ax^2+bx+c)} dx$

Tags: calculus

Setting our integral to $I$ and squaring it:
$$
I = \int_0^\infty e^{-(ax^2+bx+c)} dx
$$
$$
I^2 = e^{-2c}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-(a(x^2+y^2) + b(x+y))}dxdy
$$
I want to convert to polar co-ordinates but I get an ugly expression and depending on the values of $a$ and $b$ we will not obtain circular symmetry:
$$
I^2 =e^{-2c} \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-ar^2 - br\sqrt{1+2\sin(\theta)}}rdrd\theta
$$
Are my bounds incorrect and if so how can I change them?

Comment: In general there is no nice formula but it can be expressed using the complimentary error function:
$$I=\frac{\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}-c\right)\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)}{2\sqrt{a}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused as to whether your bounds are $[0,\infty)^2$ or $(-\infty,\infty)^2$ so I will assume it is the former. We shall say:
$$I=\int_{0}^\infty \exp(-(ax^2+bx+c))dx$$
now notice that:
$$ax^2+bx+c=\left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)$$
now lets make the substitution:
$$u=\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\Rightarrow dx=\frac{du}{\sqrt{a}}$$
so what we now have is:
$$I=\frac{\exp\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}-c\right)}{\sqrt{a}}\int\limits_{b/2\sqrt{a}}^\infty\exp(-u^2)du$$

Answer (score 5):

*Hint.* First let $x=y-b/2a$ in the original integral $I$ before squaring.